# Check/Uncheck all items in radListView

Tags: c#, telerik, checkboxlist, radlistview

I have a Telerik ListView that contains checkBox items.
[image]

So, I want in a button to Check all items and in another button to uncheck all the items in this radListView.

How can i do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution...
ToggleState.ON to check all and ToggleState.Off to Uncheck all.

```
for (int item = 0; item < AllowAccess_ListView.Items.Count; item++)
{
     AllowAccess_ListView.Items[item].CheckState = Telerik.WinControls.Enumerations.ToggleState.On;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class to them you can write a simple jQuery/JS for it.

ex: If you add the class "foo" to your items you could use something like this,

Html-

```
<button id="checkAll">bla</button>
<button id="unCheckAll">bla</button>
```

-jQuery

Check:

```
$('#checkAll').click(function () {
  $('.foo').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

Uncheck:

```
$('#unCheckAll').click(function () {
  $('.foo').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks but i am working on Windows application. how could this be implemented for WinForm and not HTML??

Comment: Oh sorry, i totally missed that, thought i had a filter on HTML/jQuery